# New Exam AWS Certified Solutions Architect - Associate (Released February 2018)

Tags: amazon-web-services

While booking for the SAA exam I saw a new version of exam. Its duration is 130 mins. I have few doubts -

-Is this the beta exam that was launched last year?

-Has anyone taken this exam?

if yes -

- How many questions are there in new exam?
- Is this course still relevant w.r.t new exam?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about certification

Comment: I know the topic is closed, but in case it will be of any help I have posted the key points for the exam https://infinitypp.com/amazon-aws/certified-solutions-architect/pass-2018-aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate-exam-tips/

Comment: I passed the february 2018 exam recently and it had 65 questions.  I am not sure which course are you talking about but I wrote a post with a few  notes and resources that I used: http://ignaciosuay.com/how-i-prepared-for-the-aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate-exam/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon publishes details of both exams on their web site. The new exam looks like a better choice than the previous exam. Given the statement:

> "We have recently updated this exam to cover new services and
>   architectural best practices."

I would take the new exam as this better fits with current AWS services and features.

Note: People who take the exam are not allowed to provide details of the exam. I have not taken the new exam. I have the SA Pro, so I am automatically recertified for the associate.

- Number of questions: 65 (compared to 60 for the older exam)
- Time to complete exam: 130 minutes (compared to 80 mins for the older exam)

However, given the new longer time to complete the exam and fewer questions, I  expect that the questions are harder and better thought out than the previous exam (which sometime made me ask "Who wrote that question?").

[AWS Certified Solutions Architect - Associate](https://aws.amazon.com/certification/certified-solutions-architect-associate/)

[Certified Solutions Architect Associate Exam Guide](https://d1.awsstatic.com/training-and-certification/docs-sa-assoc/AWS_Certified_Solutions_Architect_Associate_Feb_2018_%20Exam_Guide_v1.5.2.pdf)

Comment: https://techcloudonline.com is having a lot of free updated practice test